# WYSIWYG/M for circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

Has anyone found a way to take circuits build in some kind of CAD programs like LTSpice, etc - and use those files to generate TeX images?

Comment: You could save the circuit as pdf or ps file and just include the file.

Comment: Visually - they look really gross though.  That's all :P

Comment: Maybe, have a look at http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/ . I have to say that I had a stability issue with the software (I played with the software for roughly 45 min on my Windows system). But you can export the circuit as a vector graphic and save the description/text as tex-file.

Comment: Might be a bit OffTopic, but anyway;) I always liked the style that Razavi
uses in his books and papers[1], does some know what software he might use or is it just visio with a different set of stencils?                                  [1]http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Conferences/BRazaviCICC13.pdf

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to parse the netlist and generate a circuitikt-picture, but it is not easy... And should be implemented directly at the tex-environment, perhaps with a lua-script?

Comment: As it stands this feels too broad to me, sorry.